# How to decouple logging implementation and API?

Tags: java, logging

I'm creating a small Java framework, which will log its events. I don't want the framework to be dependent on any particular logging implementation ([jul](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html), [commons logging](http://commons.apache.org/logging/), [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/), [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/), [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/), etc). Instead, I want to allow my clients to choose anything they prefer.

The question is - how should I realize such decoupling? How my framework should log its events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that will be difficult to achieve as your code must call something in order to log information and error messages.  I think you will have to choose one (I recommend slf4j) and stick to it - this seems to be what is generally done by everyone else.

Answer (score 6):

slf4j is designed to solve exactly this problem: it decouples the API from the logging implementation.

slf4j is not a logging implementation by itself. It depends on the existence of a back-end implementation. Logback just happens to natively implement the slf4j API but there are bindings for log4j, java.util.Logging and others.

At some level you **must** have an API for your clients to use. You might as well make it one of the existing APIs rather than writing your own.

Answer (score 0):

I would include support for [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) and [Commons Logging](http://commons.apache.org/logging/).

Comment: I'm going to add my own comment to say that this is a solved problem in other frameworks, most notably Spring. Spring 3.x already has support for Apache Commons Logging, which itself is merely a logging interface with a basic implementation attached by default.